# Count number of clusters in masked image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to identify the number of clusters in a masked image of a processed MRI. The blobs image segmentation tutorial that has been previously recommended doesn't seem to help too much. Even if you could link me to a resource, that would be great! I have attached a sample image below.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to:

(i) Create a binary image, which you already seem to have.

(ii) Create a connected components labeling. Check out `bwlabel(BW, conn)` (1)

`BW` is your binary image, `conn` is the connectivity In other words, you want to check, which of the white dots are 'islands', i.e., have a direct connection to other white pixels. Therefore, you have to decide what a connection is, i.e., do you only look North, East, South, West, or also diagonally, i.e. North-East, ... etc. You may want to postprocess your clusters further, in case you want clusters that are very close to each other, but not connected, to be the same (fill holes, i.e. with morphological operators).

(iii) Check the numbers of unique non-zero values in your connected component labeling to receive the number of clusters. Try `unique` (2) and `length`.

(1) https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html

(2) https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html

This is what it should look like:

[image: Connected Component Labeling]

Comment: oh interesting! thank you very much for the help.